# JQuery add <a> element to td with Cell Index Row Index

Tags: jquery, html

I have data from database that needs to be placed according to the cell index and row index as shown:

```
<script>
        $('.myTable tr:eq( <?php echo $row; ?> )').find('td:eq(<?php echo $col; ?>)').text('<?php echo $data; ?>');
</script>
```

But how do I add link to the td? 
I've tried this:

```
<script>
        $('.myTable tr:eq( <?php echo $row; ?> )').find('td:eq(<?php echo $col; ?>)').html('<?php echo "<a href='#' id='data'>" .$data. "</a>"; ?>');
</script>
```

and this:

```
<script>
        $('.myTable tr:eq( <?php echo $row; ?> )').find('td:eq(<?php echo $col; ?>)').append('<?php echo "<a href='#' id='data'>" .$data. "</a>"; ?>');
</script>
```

But none is working. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `.$data.` change to `+$data+` to concat properly in JS. concat using `.` is for php

Comment: Why don't you directly output your data via PHP in the HTML? Looks like that's what you want to do

Comment: thanks @guradio ! I wasted whole day looking for the answer and turns out to be my silly mistake

Comment: @Qin glad to help

Comment: @MehulMohan I'm not sure of the right way, still playing around with the cellindex rowindex in JQuery. Mind pointing out how to do that in PHP?

Comment: @Qin i suggest go for ajax request. read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @guradio the + concat was working but turns out it was summing up my output in integer =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var data = '<?php echo $data; ?>';
    $('.myTable tr:eq( <?php echo $row; ?> )').find('td:eq(<?php echo $col; ?>)').html("<a href='#' id='data'>"+ data +"</a>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
        $('.myTable tr:eq( <?php echo $row; ?> )').find('td:eq(<?php echo $col; ?>)').html('<?php echo "<a href=\'#\' id=\'data\'>" .$data. "</a>"; ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: what do you expect him to do and what's the result?

Comment: it is suppose to display something like <td><a href="#"> the echoed data </a></td> according to the index from database

Comment: I tought that the problem was the href, you didn't explain the problem

Comment: I didn't know where the problem was either because the whole thing wouldn't appear.